# black parts of GTK+ windows

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk, gtk3

When I install GTK+ theme, I got these black parts on windows:

I've tried different GTK+ themes, even default Adwaita has the same problem. When choosing Ambiance or Radiance - it works fine.

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04, and Gnome 3.14.

How to fix this?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu and Gnome Shell are you using, and where did you install the theme from?

Comment: oh, forgot to mention. Gnome 3.14, Ubuntu 15.04 - I've updated my post

Answer (score 1):

- First, make sure the needed GTK engines are installed.

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine
  ```

  If that works after restarting the shell (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> & <kbd>r</kbd> & <kbd>Enter</kbd>), great! Otherwise, disable the theme for now and continue.
- You can then install it from source if needed  to get the latest version:

  - By using the package from [here](http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/Horst3180/xUbuntu_15.04/all/) or the repoistory [here](https://software.opensuse.org/download.html?project=home%3AHorst3180&package=vertex-theme).
  - By compiling from source [the source on GitHub](https://github.com/horst3180/Vertex-theme) - read the README to find out what you need to do.
- Enable the theme again, and restart the shell with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> & <kbd>r</kbd> & <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: gtk2-engines-murrine was already installed. It's not the Vertex theme problem. I've tried for now about 5 new themes. And all of them have such problems (even Adwaita, default - after install). Only 2 themes don't have such bug: Radiance and Ambiance

Comment: @Evghenii - it may be a issue with Ubuntu's version of GTK, but I would suggest reporting a bug [here](https://github.com/horst3180/Vertex-theme/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen) if you can't get the source version to work.